# How to prove $(1-\frac1{36})^{25}\lt\frac12$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality, elementary-functions

How to prove the inequality?

$(1-\frac1{36})^{25}\lt\frac12$

---

I'm in trouble.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try a binomial expansion, that should get you there.

Comment: Binomial expansion won't work so well--you'd need to sum at least the first 5 terms to ensure the LHS is less than $1/2$.

Comment: $\log_{1/2}(1-\frac1{36}) \approx 0.04064\cdots$ and so $25$ is tight here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The series
$$(1-x)^{-25}=1+25 x+325 x^2 + 2925 x^3+20\,475 x^4+\ldots$$
has all coefficients positive. It follows that
$$\left(1-{1\over36}\right)^{-25}> 1+{25\over 36}+{325\over 36^2}+{2916\over 36^3}=1+{25\over36}+{325+81\over 36^2}={1301\over648}>2\ .$$

Comment: +1 This is a very good observation! (and one term fewer than the direct approach)

Comment: This is truly a beautiful answer with the least amount of mathematical machinery being used. +1.

Answer (score 19):

Note that $\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{36}\approx e^{-1}$, but more specifically $\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{36}\lt e^{-1}$ (because the function $\left(1-\frac1x\right)^x$ is increasing for $x\gt 1$ and its limit as $x\to\infty$ is $e^{-1}$).  Thus, $\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{25} =\left(\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{36}\right)^{\frac{25}{36}}\lt e^{-\frac{25}{36}}$.  But we have $e^{-\frac{25}{36}}\lt\frac12$ because $e^{\frac{25}{36}}\gt 2$ because $\frac{25}{36}\gt\ln 2$.  This last equation can easily be checked with a small table of constants.

Comment: Please the proof I posted. I only use the binomial expansion theorem without using the property of $(1-\frac{1}{x})^x$.

Answer (score 10):

We have that $\displaystyle\left(1-\frac{1}{36}\right)^{25}=\sum_{r=0}^{25} \binom{25}{r}(-1)^{r}\frac{1}{36^r}=1-\frac{25}{36}+\frac{25\cdot24}{2\cdot36^2}-\frac{25\cdot24\cdot23}{6\cdot36^3}+\frac{25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22}{24\cdot36^4}-\cdots$.

Since the sum is alternating and has terms that are decreasing in absolute value, its value is less than

$\displaystyle1-\frac{25}{36}+\frac{25\cdot24}{2\cdot36^2}-\frac{25\cdot24\cdot23}{6\cdot36^3}+\frac{25\cdot24\cdot23\cdot22}{24\cdot36^4}=\frac{29}{54}-\frac{25\cdot23\cdot122}{36^4}<\frac{1}{2}$ since

$27(25)(23)(122)>27(24)(23)(120)=9(12^{2})(3)(2)(23)(10)=36^{2}(1380)>36^2(1296)=36^{4}$

$\implies\displaystyle\frac{25\cdot23\cdot122}{36^{4}}>\frac{1}{27}.$

Comment: Why the downvote? I was about to post something similar.

Comment: @robjohn  downvote is not from me,  I precious little (if have one)  downvote on this site

Comment: @robjohn At least the vote total for my answer isn't negative (yet).

Comment: @robjohn I downvoted because similar to user165670's comment on Darksonn's answer, I do not feel this is a good approach. The question is not asking for calculator use, and even if it was this would not be a good way to use the calculator - you could just plug the number directly in and get a decimal output. Or at least use logs, as in Steven's approach.

Comment: @notnotlogical, what calculator is able to compute $36^{25}$? Note that $36^{4}$ is altogether more palatable. Although I admit that Steven's answer is slightly "cleaner".

Comment: @ChrisK Python, any other computer language, Wolfram, ... I don't know. I suggested using logs if necessary...

Comment: Actually my calculator just computed it easily. I have a TI.

Comment: @NotNotLogical This method does not really require a calculator. It only involves adding and subtracting fractions. On the contrary, how would one compute $\log$ without a calculator? (I know how, but it's a lot more complicated.)

Comment: @NotNotLogical, I disagree that the methods are the same. Suppose I change the question to $(35/36)^{100}$ or $(35/36)^{1000}$ and so forth. Push the limit of the calculator and you can more easily calculate it using the above method. And on a test that might be more useful.

Comment: @ChrisK You can use logs, and then exponentiate at the end. I'm not saying the method doesn't work, I just don't think a brute force computation is what is being looked for - the asker could have done that for his/her self.

Comment: @NotNotLogical, fair enough. I do agree this is not the best method, but prefer it to just computing $(35/36)^{25}$ directly though.

Answer (score 8):

Here I present a basic proof only using the binomial expansion theorem without using the property of $(1-\frac{1}{x})^x$. Note that the inequality is equivalent to the following inequality
$$ \left(\frac{36}{35}\right)^{25}> 2.$$
By the binomial expansion theorem, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{36}{35}\right)^{25}&=&\left(1+\frac{1}{35}\right)^{25}\\
&>&1+\binom{25}{1}\frac{1}{35}+\binom{25}{2}\frac{1}{35^2}+\binom{25}{3}\frac{1}{35}\\
&=&1+\frac{25}{35}+\frac{25\cdot 24}{2}\frac{1}{35^2}+\frac{25\cdot24\cdot23}{3\cdot 2}\frac{1}{35^3}\\
&=&1+\frac{5}{7}+\frac{12}{49}+\frac{92}{1715}\\
&=&1+\frac{1737}{1715}\\
&>&2.
\end{eqnarray}
Done.

Comment: +1 Similar in idea to Christian Blatter's answer; that is, all positive terms. Both require one fewer term than the alternating versions, which require one more term in order to end with a positive term.

Comment: @robjohn, thanks. I only used high school math. Christian Blatter used a result from Calculus.

Comment: Your version of 25 choose 3 needs a factor of 2 in its denominator. However with that corrected you still get the $1+1737/1715$ answer, so maybe the 2 factor just got dropped in your entering things. (And +1).

Comment: @coffeemath, thanks. I corrected. It is a typo.

Comment: If you invoke $92\gt91=7\cdot13$, you can simplify the denouement to $$1+{1\over7}\left(5+{12\over7}+{13\over35}\right)=1+{1\over7}\left(5+{73\over35}\right)=1+{1\over7}\left(5+2+{3\over35}\right)\gt2$$

Comment: Nice solution -- I like this better than using the alternating series.

Comment: Indeed. This uses the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) rather than the [generalized binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton.27s_generalised_binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 5):

Take logarithms

Left Hand Side $= 25(\log 35 - \log 36) = -.30586...$;
Right Hand Side $= -\log 2= -.30102...$

Left Hand Side is less than the Right Hand Side

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I thought your answer was the least messy, calculation-wise, of the answers I've seen so far. You can use Mathjax to improve the formatting. For more on the basics of Mathjax, see [the MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 5):

Using logarithms, as already said, you have to show that $$25\ln\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)<-\ln(2)$$ A very good Taylor expansion of logarithms is given by $$\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2 \Big(\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+....\Big)$$ defining $x$ from $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac{35}{36}$ gives $x=-\frac{1}{71}$ which is quite small and the first term should be sufficient. So,$$25\ln\left(\frac{35}{36}\right) \simeq -\frac{50}{71} \simeq -0.704225$$ which is already smaller than $-\ln(2) \simeq -0.693147$. If we use a second term (remember that $x <0$ and that we raise it to the third power), then the difference with still increase since $$25\ln\left(\frac{35}{36}\right) \simeq -50\Big(\frac{1}{71}+ \frac{1}{3 \times 71^3}\Big)=-\frac{756200}{1073733}\simeq -0.704272$$

Answer (score 4):

Without using either large numbers, large amount of terms or evaluating the value as decimal, I can't think of any way to solve this, here's one way that involves large numbers

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
&\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{25}\\
=&\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{25}\\
=&\frac{35^{25}}{36^{25}}\\
=&\frac{399669593472470313551127910614013671875}{808281277464764060643139600456536293376}
\end{array}
$$

Since if $\frac ab < \frac12$ then $2a < b$

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
&399669593472470313551127910614013671875\times 2\\
=&799339186944940627102255821228027343750
\end{array}
$$

Now we have 2 integers, we can compare these
$$
\begin{array}{c}
799339186944940627102255821228027343750\\
808281277464764060643139600456536293376
\end{array}
$$
Obviously the lower number is the largest, so the inequality holds.

Comment: How did you calculate? It is awesome!!!

Comment: @xpaul The numbers were easily calculated with a calculator.

Comment: @Darksonn, please see my proof.

Answer (score 2):

Using logarithms, but without the aid of a calculator, you need to show $$25\ln\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)<-\ln(2)$$ which is the same as $$25\ln(7)+25\ln(5)-50\ln(3)-49\ln(2)<0$$

Now at this point, you go old-school and have $\ln$ of various prime numbers memorized:

$$25(1.9549\ldots)+25(1.6094\ldots)-50\ln(1.0986\ldots)-49(0.6931\ldots)$$

which is a net negative.

Answer (score 2):

All answers so far have been approximations of the value or its logarithm. As such, none seem particularly appealing. However, using the binomial theorem seems most appealing to me since it can be done with the least computation, and a good bit of reused computation. Therefore, this computation can reasonably be performed by hand, and this is what I think the question is asking for since given a calculator it is not too hard simply to compute
$$
\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{25}=0.49446845
$$

The approach in this answer has already been given in the [answer by user84413](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/885156), and I think it is the simplest to compute since each binomial coefficient is quite easy to compute from the last and the same is true for powers of $\frac1{36}$.

It should also be pointed out that any error from rounding in one term is multiplied by a factor of less than $1$ before being passed on to the next term, so each term should be accurate to the last digit, so even though the computation below is only carried out to $4$ decimal places, the error should be less than $0.00005\times4=0.0002$. (In fact, the computation turns out to be correct to the last decimal place.)
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-\frac1{36}\right)^{25}
&\le1-\frac{\binom{25}{1}}{36^1}+\frac{\binom{25}{2}}{36^2}-\frac{\binom{25}{3}}{36^3}+\frac{\binom{25}{4}}{36^4}\\
&=1-\frac{25}{36}+\color{#808080}{\frac{25}{36}}\frac{24}{2\cdot36}-\color{#808080}{\frac{25}{36}\frac{24}{2\cdot36}}\frac{23}{3\cdot36}+\color{#808080}{\frac{25}{36}\frac{24}{2\cdot36}\frac{23}{3\cdot36}}\frac{22}{4\cdot36}\\[6pt]
&=1-0.6944+0.2315-0.0493+0.0075\\[9pt]
&=0.4953\\[9pt]
&\lt0.5000
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please see my proof.

Comment: @xpaul: already did :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use that $\ln(1 - x) < -x$ (which is immediate from the power series for $\ln(1 - x)$) then it can be done quite quickly. Taking logs your inequality is equivalent to
$$25 \ln \bigg(1 - {1 \over 36}\bigg) < \ln (1/2)$$
Using $\ln(1 - x) < -x$ it suffices to show that
$$-{25 \over 36} < \ln (1/2)$$
Equivalently,
$$\ln 2 < {25 \over 36}$$
Note that $\ln 2 = .6931...$  and ${25 \over 36} = .6944..$

So the inequality does hold.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the inequality holds iff $35/36<(1/2)^{1/25}.$ The continued fraction for the latter number starts out $[0;1,35,1,1,3,11,...]$ and the even convergents are all less than $(1/2)^{1/25}.$ The first even convergent (i.e. the second convergent) is $0+1/(1+1/35)=35/36,$ so this shows the inequality, provided one is allowed to use the computation of the continued fraction. The next even convergent, the fourth, is $71/73$, and its 25th power is again less than $1/2$ and so on.

*Edit:* Note that I had to use decimal evaluations to obtain the first few terms of the continued fraction for $(1/2)^{1/25}.$ In a way that is a drawback, since just finding the decimal $(1/2)^{1/25} \approx 0.97265$ already finishes the problem, since $35/36 \approx 0.972222.$ However maybe there is a way to get the continued fraction, at least the first two entries, without resorting to decimals. Things here are more complicated than in the easier case of squareroots, in which rationalizing works at the steps. It was easy enough getting to $[0;1]$ for the (trivial) first convergent, but trying to actually prove it continues $[0;1,35]$ didn't seem to give any nice provable calculation because of the presence of 25th roots.

However it did seem like an interesting coincidence that the second convergent came out exactly the $35/36$ of the posted inequality.

Comment: How did you get the continued fraction for $\left(\frac12\right)^{1/25}$?

Comment: @robjohn Just using the usual method but with the aid of decimal approximations, as noted in the edit. I only used a simple calculator without a lot of accuracy, but am sure at least of the $[0;1,35]$ beginning of it.

Comment: So you computed $\left(\frac12\right)^{1/25}$ first? Why bother computing the continued fraction?

Comment: @robjohn I agree with your comment, as I tried to explain in the edit: "that is a drawback", but I found it of some interest that $35/36$ turned out to be an even convergent, so less. And the use of continued fractions here seems overkill given e.g. yours or xpauls answers.